# Effects of pruning a decision tree on the accuracy of the test set and training set

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, decision-tree

I would like to improve my understanding on how pruning would affect the accuracy of the training and test sets.

My current understanding is that it will improve accuracy on the test set because pruning prevents the tree from overfitting. Is this the right idea?

And how would pruning affect the accuracy on the training set? I think it reduces accuracy but why?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pruning might lower the accuracy of the training set, since the tree will not learn the optimal parameters *as well* for the training set. However, if we do not overcome overfitting by setting the appropriate parameters, we might end up building a model that will *fail to generalize*.

That means that the model has learnt an overly complex function, which perfectly predicts on the train data, but which will fail to generalize with unseen data. This is more of an issue when we have lower training sets, since the set in itself might not be representative enough of new samples that can come in the future.

So you need to take care of these parameters to limit the maximum depth and the number of leafs to prevent the model from being too complex.

You might want to read also about the [Bias–variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff).